# "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key " in cvs DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, opencsv

Pandas ValueError: "Columns must be same length as key"
I am using Jupyter Labs for this. receiving the a error "Columns must be same length as key". the error is at "df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)"

in file1.cvs

| research_groups_names |
| --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) |
| CAS |
| U-M |
| UQ |

in file2.cvs

| research_groups_names | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) | China |
| University of Michigan (U-M) | United States of America (USA) |
| The University of Queensland (UQ) | Australia |

the Output.csv

| f1_research_groups_names | f2_research_groups_names | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chinese Academy of Sciences | Chinese Academy ofSciences(CAS) | China |
| CAS | Chinese Academy of Sciences (CAS) | China |
| U-M | University of Michigan (U-M) | United States of America(USA) |
| UQ | The University of Queensland (UQ) | Australia |

```
  import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
    
    df2 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

    df1 = df1.add_prefix('f1_')
    df2 = df2.add_prefix('f2_')

def fn(row):
    for _, n in df2.iterrows():
        if (
            n["research_groups_names"] == row["research_groups_names"]
            or row["research_groups_names"] in n["research_groups_names"]
        ):
            return n


df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename(columns={"research_groups_names": "f1_research_groups_names"})
print(df1)
```

Comment: `file2.csv`  (presumably a typo) is 3 rows long and the other two files are 4 rows long. This is where the error comes from. Add an extra row to file2 and confirm that this resolves the issue.

Comment: it didn't work , row count for file1.csv 4000 , and for file2.csv is about 13,000

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.