# Pandas ValueError: Columns must be same length as key in merge withe large database

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

Pandas ValueError: "Columns must be same length as key" I am using Jupyter Labs for this. receiving the a error "Columns must be same length as key". the error is at "df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)"

```
import pandas as pd
    df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
    
    df2 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

    df1 = df1.add_prefix('f1_')
    df2 = df2.add_prefix('f2_')

def fn(row):
    for _, n in df2.iterrows():
        if (
            n["research_groups_names"] == row["research_groups_names"]
            or row["research_groups_names"] in n["research_groups_names"]
        ):
            return n


df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]] = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename(columns={"research_groups_names": "f1_research_groups_names"})
print(df1)
```

Comment: looks like an issue with the data,  please show example with the data:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72958605/valueerror-columns-must-be-same-length-as-key-in-cvs-dataframe     -----  cvs row count for file1.csv 4000 data, and for file2.csv I have about 13,000 ---- I tried add this but it didn't work df1[["f2_research_groups_names", "f2_location"]].str.split(' - ', expand=True, n=1) = df1.apply(fn, axis=1)

Comment: I posted 2 questions

Comment: I answered the other question.   The middle file is missing a row of data compared to the other two files.  Please confirm that this resolves the problem.